# Student Project Allocation (SPA)

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I understand "Stable Marriage Problem" (SMP) with its constraints and implement part of it in prolog, but I was wondering how I can extend my solution to include also "Student Project Allocation" (SPA)Problem . What are the actual differences between them ?. 
As I understand, but I am not sure:
In "Stable marriage problem", I have relation one-to-one between man and woman, but in SPA since each professor has quota and also each project has quota, so the relation will be many-to-many ?, Is that right ?, and is there any possibility to use same solution of SMP in SPA ?

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that:
1. **Student** chooses **Project** 
2. The project itself belongs to one and only one lecture

In SMP a person propose to his/her partner
In SPA a student choose the project

Differences (might not be differences since that is just when to accepts the proposal):
SMP: The one proposed is free and prefer that one :)
SPA: The project is free, still accept student in the project, the professor of that project still have quota.

Comment: Thanks, but what Should I do in case I have specific Quota and there are many other students still need that project, should he select the next prefer project ?

Comment: Use the prefer list to decide whether keep or reject the new application from student.